# Show/Hide Html TR/TD

Tags: jquery, css

How can I show/hide any `tr/td` from the html table?
I should be able to hide any tr/td from the table as show in the screen shot.

```
<table id="tableEditor" >
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">
      <select name="select">
        <option value="value1">USA</option>
        <option value="value2"  >Sweden</option>
        <option value="value3">Norway</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>Inventory ID</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">$123.23</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">$312.21</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">this is a description</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
#tableEditor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}

body,
th,
td {
  font: normal 12pt Verdana;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 2px;
}
```

[image]
Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/s6jcfa7m/)

Comment: okay I did but why down-vote? care to explain

Comment: okay i have added css as well.. the reason i did not have in first place is not to have too much code and also i do not think it will make any difference with my css and there is no impact whatsoever, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include jQuery, all you need to do is this:

```
$("td:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(4)").hide();
```

Here's a fork of your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccbsa9z3/2/

You can also do the same thing with CSS, although I'm assuming you need to do this programmatically. With CSS, it's the following:

```
td:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(4) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it with just CSS, use `:nth-of-type()`:

```
td:nth-of-type(2),
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bLvtvnc0/)

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element with Javascript, use

```
element.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

To hide an element with CSS, use

```
visibility: hidden;
```

To completely remove an element with CSS, use

```
display: none;
```

I [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6jcfa7m/5/) to hide an arbitrary TD using each of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r9jnc8n6/)

1. You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

   > Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

   `$('#tableEditor tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();`

   `$('#tableEditor tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').toggle();`
2. You can also add a class with a display none

   `$('#tableEditor tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').addClass('hidden');`

   `$('#tableEditor tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').addClass('hidden');`

Answer (score 0):

You should place the column titles on a `thead` element, and the content in a `tbody`:

```
<table id="tableEditor">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>Inventory ID</td>
            <td>Cost</td>
            <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
            <select name="select">
                <option value="value1">USA</option>
                <option value="value2"  >Sweden</option>
                <option value="value3">Norway</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align:left;">$123.23</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">$312.21</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">this is a description</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can set the `display` of each cell you want to hide to `none`.

You can see this in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6jcfa7m/2/).

Comment: there is a reason why I have that the way, i do not see anything in action, its just displaying the table with different formatting.

Comment: I'm just suggesting you should try to fix the formatting instead of hacking around it...if possible.